# User data with JWT

Tags: php, jwt

I'm thinking of migrating a PHP session based user portal to JWT stateless API and I'm not too sure if I'm understanding this right.

What should the access token store? The user database has an auto increment primary key for user id, username and email address. All the relational tables in the DB are referenced by user id. I don't know if it's good practice to pass the user id in the public token. I'm thinking maybe pass the email address but this means that I would have to pull the user record every page load so that I can access the other tables via the user id.

Also, how do I pass user details to the next page? Previously I would store these fields in $_SESSION on login but that's not possible now. Does this mean I have to pull the user record manually each time?

Finally, how do I invalidate tokens on logout?

Thanks!

Comment: You don't invalidate them, you simply remove them from the browser.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do anything on Log Out.Just Remove Token from user's browser
i.e `function logout(){
   localStorage.removeItem(key);
}`

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason why you should fear exposing your user ID in your JWT. All JWT does is that it has a payload (say your user's email, name, user ID, and etc.), a header (the type of encryption used) and a signature (your encoded header, payload, and a secret). What you are simply doing is that whenever you want to verify if the JWT is valid, you simply check it with the private key that you have stored somewhere secure on the server.

This means that the JWT payload can reduce the amount of database connections and queries made, because you simply do not have to double check with the DB all the time. All you need is for the server to verify the JWT, on page load, for each transaction, and etc., with an internally stored private key.

User details can simply be obtained from the payload (which is only base 64 encoded, not encrypted at all), so you can either use `$_COOKIE[]` in PHP (which is transmitted as part of the HTTP request) or use JS to decode the payload on the client side.

JWT can be invalidated by simply deleting it from the user cookies or local storage. There are many ways of invalidating it, such as:

- when you detect it has lived past its expiry date
- when you detect it has been manipulated with such that the signature verification based on your private key has failed

Comment: JWT only reduces the number of database connections for validating the user. The user details still need to be pulled from the DB for the request anyway. I'm just worried of the JWT token being "stolen" and the information in the payload being easily decrypted.
Doesn't storing the details in $_COOKIE defeat the purpose of moving to stateless JWT?